# SAS conditionals applied to array elements

Tags: arrays, sas

I have a hard time wrapping my head around SAS arrays. I have a dataset that has ID and BeginDate, EndDate. I want to create 3 binary variables that =1 if either start or enddate is in a given year and I'm looking at 3 different years. When I run the code below all of the new variables I create (year1955, year1956, year1957) = 1 if any one of them is true. This is not what I want.  I am using an array because I eventually will want to do this with more than 3 variables.

My code:

```
data temp2; set temp; 
array yr(3) year1955-year1957; 
do i = 1 to 3; 
     if year(BeginDate) =1955 or year(EndDate)=1955 then yr(i)=1;
     if year(BeginDate) =1956 or year(EndDate)=1956 then yr(i)=1;
     if year(BeginDate) =1957 or year(EndDate)=1957 then yr(i)=1;
end;
drop i;
run;
```

I would be open to a more elegant solution than the one I've devised.

Output I'm getting :

```
ID  Begindate   EndDate    year1955 year1956 year1957

AA  01/01/1956  01/01/1969    1          1        1
```

Output I want:

```
ID  Begindate   EndDate    year1955 year1956 year1957

AA  01/01/1956  01/01/1969    .          1        .
```

Comment: Technical questions on the web are much better with a useful and descriptive title - "help" or "easy fix" doesn't tell people what the problem is about. I have tried to improve it, but feel free to amend further.

Answer (score 2):

You are not use the value of your loop variable in the IF conditions.

You could just get rid of the DO loop.

```
 if year(BeginDate) =1955 or year(EndDate)=1955 then yr(1)=1;
 if year(BeginDate) =1956 or year(EndDate)=1956 then yr(2)=1;
 if year(BeginDate) =1957 or year(EndDate)=1957 then yr(3)=1;
```

Or include the value I in the IF condition.

```
do i = 1 to 3; 
 if year(BeginDate) =1955+i-1 or year(EndDate)=1955+i-1 then yr(i)=1;
end;
```

Or use the year value as the index into the array by changing the range of indexes the array uses.

```
array yr [1955:1957] year1955-year1957; 
if year(BeginDate) in (1955:1957) then yr[year(BeginDate)]=1;
if year(EndDate) in (1955:1957) then yr[year(EndDate)]=1;
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I like the solution #3 the best, but all are very helpful

Comment: @AkuAnda One other nice feature of SAS - You can create a binary 1/0 variable with this shortcut: `yr[i] = (year(BeginDate) in (1955:1957)).` This will automatically evaluate to 1 or 0 if the condition is true or false.